Unity useLegacyPackaging problem solution
Hello i have some problem.
I couldn't figure it out as nothing. Could it be related to Google Mobile Ads? I was able to extract an aab file 1 hour ago but now it doesn't and I didn't make any changes to my code. I tried deleting the library but it didn't work. I created about 20 of these aab files, it was the same project, I didn't make any changes to the codes. It crashed on its own. I tried a clean build as well. I closed and reopened Unity, still the same problem.

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING:The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is deprecated.
The current default is 'true'.
It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You can add the following to your build.gradle instead:
android {
    packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging = true
        }
    }
}
IncrementalTaskInputs has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. On method 'IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core' use 'org.gradle.work.InputChanges' instead. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.3/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#incremental_task_inputs_deprecation

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :UnityDataAssetPack:generateAssetPackManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:processReleaseAssetPackManifests
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:writeReleaseAarMetadata
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:linkReleaseManifestForAssetPacks FAILED
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
26 actionable tasks: 26 executed

UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu (object,string[],int)

maintemplate.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:12
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.2.0' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.2.0' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleUmpDependencies.xml:7
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
**DEPS**}

// Android Resolver Exclusions Start
android {
  packagingOptions {
        exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
        exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
        exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
        exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
        exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')

        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging = true
        }
    }

}
// Android Resolver Exclusions End
android {
    ndkPath "**NDKPATH**"

    compileSdkVersion 35
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 35
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = **BUILTIN_NOCOMPRESS** + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS**
}
**IL_CPP_BUILD_SETUP**
**SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
**EXTERNAL_SOURCES**

I changed some codes.
